# d3 - Set Initial transform and scale matching with mouse zoom and drag event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

currently I am trying to save and load layout to the DB, so after users added, removed, dragged, zoomed nodes, I load everything from the DB, everything is just the same when they saved, but the zoom scale and the transform of the canvas is messing up when users drag on the canvas or using mouse wheel to zoom in zoom out.

So my question how to matching the initial translate and zoom scale of the layout.

I did try so set attribute of the canvas to this translate(494.42565082250155,80.8046875) scale(0.49999999999999994)

but when use mouse to zoom, it just reset translate and zoomscale to translate(0,0) scale(1)

here is my code to handle the zoom

```
var svg = d3.select("svg").call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
})).append("g");
svg.on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```